# NullPointerException in the Adapter for a Custom View

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception, android-custom-view

I have a problem with the following exception:

```
exception:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

I have an `Adapter` class:

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater lInflater;
    private String [] simpleValueList;

    public SimpleAdapter(Context context, String[] simpleValueList) {
        lInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.simpleValueList = simpleValueList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return simpleValueList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return simpleValueList[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.test, parent, false);

            TextView textSimple = view.findViewById(R.id.simple_list);
            textHours.setText(simpleValueList[position]);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

my CustomView class:

```
public class SimpleView extends View {

    private String[] valueList = {"aa", "2", "bb", "3"};
    private ListView listView;
    private SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;

    public SimpleView(Context context, ViewGroup mviewGroup) {
        super(context);
        inflate(context, R.layout.test, mviewGroup);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.simple_list);
        simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, valueList);
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
  }
}
```

my Activity class:

```
public class SimpleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SimpleView simpleView;

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.custom_view);
        simpleView = new SimpleView(this, linearLayout);
        linearLayout.addView(simpleView);
    }
}
```

test. xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/simple_list"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/orange" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/custom_view"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
 </LinearLayout>
```

If I do not add the `Adapter` in the `SimpleView` class then it works. But if I add the `Adapter` in the `SimpleView` class I get the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference. (at ...here: listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter); (simpleView = new SimpleView(this, linearLayout));
```

Comment: Hi Julia. The code is calling the SimpleView's version of findViewById  which is using test.xml [View.findViewById](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#findViewById(int)), but the ListView is in activity_main.xml in the Activity.

Comment: @Elletlar Do you mean this:  listView = findViewById(R.id.custom_view1) ? Hello:)

Comment: Yes. It won't find the ListView because it is calling the version of findViewbyId in "SimpleView extends View" rather than findViewbyId in the Activity where the ListView is located.

Comment: @Elletlar see: if I in test.xml file changed <TextView> to <ListView> and do this:  listView = findViewById(R.id.simpleList); - I get the same exception.

Comment: If you see the answer below, I would probably fix it by getting rid of the SimpleView and working with the ListView in onCreate of the Activity. But if you want to keep the custom view, in addition to changing it to ListView you would have to update the andorid:id.

Comment: The code is looking for a ListView with the ID: "listView = findViewById(R.id.custom_view1);"

Comment: @Julia It looks like you got the help you need, but I noticed you posted a ton of code.  In the future, please try to keep your example to a [mre], which makes it easier for people to help you.

Comment: @Charlie Armstrong, ok. sorry, I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the code is calling the `SimpleView's` version of `findViewById` which is using test.xml, but the `ListView` is located in activity_main.xml in the `SimpleActivity`.

```
listView = findViewById(R.id.custom_view1);
```

This will return null because there is no view with the ID R.id.custom_view1 inside SimpleView.

There probably is not any need for the `SimpleView` class. The following lines of code could be moved into `onCreate` in `SimpleActivity`:

```
 listView = findViewById(R.id.custom_view1);
 simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, valueList);
 listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
```

If you do want to create a CustomView on the other hand, all the views you are working with need to be in R.layout.test. You could in theory, move the `ListView` in there, but I think it is probably unnecessary. I would just inflate, find it and set the adapter in `onCreate` of the `Activity`.

If you do want an abstraction to contain the `ListView`, I would investigate putting it into a `Fragment`.

EDIT:
If it has to be done with a custom view then make sure the following is in test.xml:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/custom_view1"
    android:layout_width="71dp"
    android:layout_height="77dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">
```

It is important to use this ID `android:id="@+id/custom_view1` so that it matches up with `listView = findViewById(R.id.custom_view1);` in the Java code.

To void the crash you are getting now:

```
public SimpleView(Context context, ViewGroup mviewGroup) {
    super(context);
    View layout = inflate(context, R.layout.test, mviewGroup);
    listView = layout.findViewById(R.id.simple_list);
    simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, valueList);
    listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
}
```

Make sure you do the find on the value being returned from inflate.

=== Code Dump ===:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/custom_view_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

test.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/simple_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

ActivityMain.java:

```
package com.example.myapplication2000;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.custom_view_container);
        SimpleView simpleView = new SimpleView(this, linearLayout);
        linearLayout.addView(simpleView);
    }
}
```

SimpleView.java:

```
package com.example.myapplication2000;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SimpleView extends View {

    private String[] valueList = {"aa", "2", "bb", "3"};
    private ListView listView;
    private SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter;

    public SimpleView(Context context, ViewGroup mviewGroup) {
        super(context);
        View layout = inflate(context, R.layout.test, mviewGroup);
        listView = layout.findViewById(R.id.simple_list);
        simpleAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, valueList);
        listView.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    }

    public class SimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater lInflater;
        private String [] simpleValueList;

        public SimpleAdapter(Context context, String[] simpleValueList) {
            lInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.simpleValueList = simpleValueList;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return simpleValueList.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return simpleValueList[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) {
                view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

                TextView textSimple = view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
                textSimple.setText(simpleValueList[position]);
            }
            return view;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry, I might have changed one or two of the names. I hope it does not cause any confusion.

Also, you can clean-up the layout. There are a few 'extra' LinearLayouts that I picked up from pasting in your code, but they are not really needed.

But this code is displaying 4 list items on my device.

Comment: You see, I have task do it all in SimpleView class only. But It seems you are right.

Comment: I updated the answer to focus more on the custom view.

Comment: I changed code (please, see above), but it still gets the same exception.

Comment: maybe it is because now will be error here: TextView textSimple = view.findViewById(R.id.simple_list);
            textHours.setText(simpleValueList[position]); I don't have textView now...

Comment: I have your code working in my environment. Will post it in a second.

Comment: Oh, I m really don't know how it to do. I solve this problem the second day already and don't have success.

Comment: I posted the full code. It should work fine. I get 4 items in my list now.

Comment: thank you very much!! I couldn't solve this problem about 2 days!!! Thanks! Could you please explain, for what we did row. xml?

Comment: I changed the name to row.xml because it was easier in my mind to associate it with the ListView adapter which is for the list rows. I think the code kept crashing after you added the ListView to the SimpleView because the line "layout.findViewById(R.id.simple_list);" was needed in the SimpleView constructor. But there are still some improvements needed to make the list rows look nicer visually...

Comment: Also, if this answer helped you can you please accept it by doing: "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time"